# Log4j thread name confusion

Tags: java, java-8, log4j

The following below is a portion of our logs from our application in production. We are using **log4j**

With configuration:

```
<Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout
        pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
</Console>


[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:47:16.905 [WebContainer : 23] Logger -
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:47:16.905 [WebContainer : 23] Logger -
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:49:27.320 [WebContainer : 19] Logger - 
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:49:27.320 [WebContainer : 19] Logger - 
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:49:27.320 [WebContainer : 19] Logger - 
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:49:27.320 [WebContainer : 19] Logger - 
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:49:27.320 [WebContainer : 19] Logger - 
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:49:27.320 [WebContainer : 19] Logger - 
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:54:23.703 [WebContainer : 23] Logger - 
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:54:23.703 [WebContainer : 23] Logger - 
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:54:23.703 [WebContainer : 23] Logger - 
[INFO ] 2018-03-10 15:54:23.703 [WebContainer : 23] Logger -
```

From there you can see there is a thread name "WebContainer : 19" and "WebContainer : 23". We are confused with the thread name. Does having the same thread name mean they come from the same request? and with that we can say 15:54:23.703 happened after 2018-03-10 15:47:16.905 and belong to the same request?

or

are these thread names mean just one process group of the same class? and all the lines above can belong to the same request but just different thread names for different classes that executed in the request?

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

Each webcontainer typically has a pool of threads. All those threads keep listening for incoming TCP connections on the socket, and accepting them. Once accepted, data can be read from the newly established TCP connection, parsed, and turned into a HTTP request.

"WebContainer : 19" and "WebContainer : 23" you see in these logs are two such threads, belonging to the webcontainer thread pool. And yes, they are different.

Whenever each thread is getting its chance to execute, it is showing up in the log, hence you are observing randomization in these log statements.

To handle this random nature of threads gracefully and also to make the application behave correctly, multi-threading concepts are a must to build such applications.

Answer (score 0):

WebContainer : 23 is Thread A
WebContainer : 19 is Thread B

A and B two request is processed by WebContainer.